# How do I add colored-manpages plugin to my zsh profile (using oh-my-zsh)?

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh, plugin

I am using oh-my-zsh and in oh-my-zsh there is a plugin called colord-manpages in the listing -

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins] - [10199]
└─[$] ll | grep colored

drwxr-xr-x 2 shirish shirish 4096 2015-12-30 14:27 colored-man-pages
```

This is the output of .zshrc -

```
─[$] grep -Ev '#' .zshrc

export ZSH=/home/shirish/.oh-my-zsh

ZSH_THEME="duellj"

plugins=(last-working-dir)

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/include/SDL2"

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

and this is the output of ~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh script -

```
[$] grep -v '#' oh-my-zsh.sh                                                                                                     
if [ "$DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE" != "true" ]; then
  env ZSH=$ZSH DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT=$DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT zsh -f $ZSH/tools/check_for_upgrade.sh
fi


fpath=($ZSH/functions $ZSH/completions $fpath)

autoload -U compaudit compinit

: ${ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX:=true}

if [[ -z "$ZSH_CUSTOM" ]]; then
    ZSH_CUSTOM="$ZSH/custom"
fi

if [[ -z "$ZSH_CACHE_DIR" ]]; then
  ZSH_CACHE_DIR="$ZSH/cache"
fi


for config_file ($ZSH/lib/*.zsh); do
  custom_config_file="${ZSH_CUSTOM}/lib/${config_file:t}"
  [ -f "${custom_config_file}" ] && config_file=${custom_config_file}
  source $config_file
done


is_plugin() {
  local base_dir=$1
  local name=$2
  test -f $base_dir/plugins/$name/$name.plugin.zsh \
    || test -f $base_dir/plugins/$name/_$name
}
for plugin ($plugins); do
  if is_plugin $ZSH_CUSTOM $plugin; then
    fpath=($ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/$plugin $fpath)
  elif is_plugin $ZSH $plugin; then
    fpath=($ZSH/plugins/$plugin $fpath)
  fi
done

if [[ "$OSTYPE" = darwin* ]]; then
  SHORT_HOST=$(scutil --get ComputerName 2>/dev/null) || SHORT_HOST=${HOST/.*/}
else
  SHORT_HOST=${HOST/.*/}
fi

if [ -z "$ZSH_COMPDUMP" ]; then
  ZSH_COMPDUMP="${ZDOTDIR:-${HOME}}/.zcompdump-${SHORT_HOST}-${ZSH_VERSION}"
fi

if [[ $ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX != true ]]; then
  if ! compaudit &>/dev/null; then
    handle_completion_insecurities
  else
    compinit -d "${ZSH_COMPDUMP}"
  fi
else
  compinit -i -d "${ZSH_COMPDUMP}"
fi

for plugin ($plugins); do
  if [ -f $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/$plugin/$plugin.plugin.zsh ]; then
    source $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/$plugin/$plugin.plugin.zsh
  elif [ -f $ZSH/plugins/$plugin/$plugin.plugin.zsh ]; then
    source $ZSH/plugins/$plugin/$plugin.plugin.zsh
  fi
done

for config_file ($ZSH_CUSTOM/*.zsh(N)); do
  source $config_file
done
unset config_file

if [ "$ZSH_THEME" = "random" ]; then
  themes=($ZSH/themes/*zsh-theme)
  ((N=(RANDOM%N)+1))
  RANDOM_THEME=${themes[$N]}
  source "$RANDOM_THEME"
  echo "[oh-my-zsh] Random theme '$RANDOM_THEME' loaded..."
else
  if [ ! "$ZSH_THEME" = ""  ]; then
    if [ -f "$ZSH_CUSTOM/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme" ]; then
      source "$ZSH_CUSTOM/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme"
    elif [ -f "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme" ]; then
      source "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme"
    else
      source "$ZSH/themes/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme"
    fi
  fi
fi
```

Can anybody tell/share what I should be doing so that colored-manpages function the moment I use zsh as my xterm ?

I tried googling but couldn't find anything :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the plugin to the `plugins` definition in `.zshrc`:

```
plugins=(last-working-dir colored-man-pages)
```

Then start a new shell and you'll see the plugin activated.